# React Redux Redux form List main form application

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I use - React Redux and Redux form

I have a user list form which has table of contents with 
edit/delete buttons on the right side of each row. When I click 
on edit button it should pass the current row values to the user main form.
At the bottom of the form I have a addnew button which redirects to user main form.

My requirement is when I click addnew it should open user main form with empty fields,
when I click edit button on the table row it should open user main form with pre-populated fields with the
current selected row values.

How can I achieve this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

For Ex:

## My UserList.js form

renderUsers() {

return this.props.users.reverse().map(user => {

```
return (

    <tbody key={user._id}>

     <tr key={user._id}>

      <td>{user.email}</td>

       <td>{user.firstname}</td>

    <td><Link id={user._id} to="#" onClick={() => this.onDeleteUser(user._id)}>
<i className="material-icons">delete</i></Link>

    &nbsp;<Link id={user._id} to="user/new" 
onClick={ () => here I have to call usermain form sending the current row values}>
<i className="material-icons">edit</i></Link></td>

    </tr>

   </tbody>

);
```

});

}

render() {

return (

```
<div>

 <div><h4>User List</h4></div><hr />

    <table className="bordered highlight responsive">

     <thead>

    <tr>

    <td>Email</td>

        <td>First Name</td>
```

Action

```
        {this.renderUsers()}

   </table>
```

);

}
}

function mapStateToProps({ users}) {

return { users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUsers })(UserList);

## My User.js form

const User = () => {
  return(

```
  <UserList />

    <div className="fixed-action-btn">
      <Link to="user/new" className="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red">
        <i className="material-icons">add</i>
      </Link>
    </div>
</div>
```

);
};

export default User;

## My UserMain.js form

class UserMainForm extends Component {

renderFields() {

return _.map(userFields, ({ label, name }) => {

```
return (

  <Field

   key={name}

   component={UserField}

   label={label}

   name={name}

  />

);
```

});

}

render() {

return (

```
<div className="container" style={{marginBottom:'5px'}}>

    <div><h4>User Main { mode Edit/New}</h4></div><hr />

    <form className="container" onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(() => 
this.props.submitUser(this.props.usermainForm.values,this.props.history))}>

    <div className="row">

   {this.renderFields()}

   </div>

    <Link to="/register/user" className="red btn-flat white-text">

      Cancel
      </Link>

    <button type="submit" className="waves-effect waves-teal teal btn-flat right white-text">

        Save
        <i className="material-icons right">done</i>

   </button>

</form>

</div>

);
```

}
}

export default reduxForm({

validate,

form: 'usermainForm',

destroyOnUnmount: false
 })(UserMainForm);

Comment: The documentation has an example that shows two ways of pre-populating fields. https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/initializefromstate/

Comment: Hi Jonahe,Thank You So Much. it worked for me.

Comment: But I'm facing an issue though I'm using the same form for Create and Edit. edit populates data but create not working properly not able to enter values in the fields. How to solve this. Thanks

Comment: It's too hard to try to solve it without knowing more about your current code. Can you recreate your code (or a simpler version of it) in JSFiddle or somewhere similar? This link is a JSFiddle, made for Redux-Form, that you could use as a base. https://jsfiddle.net/bmv437/75rh036o/